Gradient overlay based on interpolated values from nearest points (heatmap?)
I have various data-points with temperature values on my Leaflet map.
I want to add a gradient-type overlay which interpolates the temperature of each pixel based on the values of the nearest known values and maps it to a color-gradient.
Quite exactly how weather maps with temperature data look like.
I've played around with all heatmap plugins for Leaflet, but they only seem to encode frequency data in their colors.

It seems that I was looking for "Inverse distance weighting" and not "heatmaps".
Someone already modified an existing Leaflet heatmap plugin to do this kind of interpolation. I haven't gotten it to work yet, but it looks promising.
https://github.com/spatialsparks/Leaflet.idw

I'll suggest using Gleo's DelaunayMesh+intensify+HeatMap, together with Leaflet.Gleo (see https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/leaflet.gleo).
Start by adding Leaflet.Gleo to your Leaflet map:
const map = new L.Map('leaflet-map');
const platina = new LeafletGleo(map, { /* optional platina options */ })

Since you want a "gradient-type" overlay, define a Gleo HeatMap with your colour ramp, e.g.:
import HeatMap from 'gleo/fields/HeatMap.mjs';
const ramp = new HeatMap(map, {
    stops: {
        0: [255, 0, 0, 0],
        10: [255, 0, 0, 255],
        20: [255, 255, 0, 255],
        30: [0, 255, 0, 255],
        40: [0, 255, 255, 255],
    },
});

The DelaunayMesh works with RGBA colours by default, but since you want to work with scalar values, apply the intensify OOP decorator to it.
import intensify from 'gleo/symboldecorators/intensify.mjs';
import DelaunayMesh from 'gleo/symbols/DelaunayMesh.mjs';
const IntensityMesh = intensify(DelaunayMesh);

Now the decorated delaunay mesh symbol can be instanced with a list of points (i.e. a multipoint geometry) and a list of scalar values (i.e. one number with the temperature of each point), e.g.:
const coords = [
    [40, -3],
    [45, -3],
    [42, 2],
    [46, 3],
    [41, 0],
];

const temps = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];

const mesh = new IntensityMesh(coords, { values: temps }).addTo(ramp);

Note how the intensity mesh is in the heatmap (ramp) which is in the gleo platina which is in the leaflet map.
The code I referenced earlier, when put together properly, should produce a result like:


Thanks! This looks great, but maybe a bit overkill?
Do you know if there's a simple Leaflet way of having Leaflet call a function of mine for each visble pixel/grid square, and my function simply returns the rgba value that should be overlayed? I think I could to the interpolation myself then.
Seems like a rather generic and useful thing to have, so I'm a bit at a loss why I can't find it.

It may look overkill, but WebGL triangles over a Delaunay mesh is the way to go if you want performance (if what you want is linearly interpolating the values of the three nearest data points). It's also a bit of a specialized use case, so that's why I've been working on generic parts that can be mixed-and-matched.
